# Renaming File With Unicode

Tags: c++

How would I place a unicode character into the file name?
I have an ostringstream that I use in defining the file name through ofstream, but I cannot use unicode characters. What would be the simplest way of doing this? Renaming it in a unicode format? And please explain how I would do so.

Comment: Use `_wfopen` to open the file with a wide-character name.

Comment: Tried using `std::wstringstream` and `std::wofstream`?

Comment: So would I basically have to convert everything using that into a wide character-compatible type?

Comment: Correct. To deal with wide-characters you have to use wide-aware functions/classes/etc.

Comment: When I try to use wofstream, I cannot use "fileName.str()" in its name, fileName being a wostringstream type. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: To be fair, I don't remember correctly whether C++11 added support for Unicode filenames. I'm sure previous C++ versions do not have it. If you're on Windows and don't need a cross-platform solution, you may **[use this](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/windows-cpp-handling-unicode-file-names.html)** (exactly what Brandon suggested in his comment), otherwise I'd prefer **[boost::filesystem::wpath](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)**. On a side note, if you're using UTF-8, I believe the POSIX API should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. If you want to place unicode character - any string/stream class there is in STL has its unicode equivalent. std::string/std::wstring, std::stringstream/std::wstringstream. If you std::wstringstream, here how you would put unicode characters into it:

```
std::wstringstream wideStream;
wideStream << L"Hello, world";
std::wstring wideString = wideStream.str();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I use wideString.str() with ofstream?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* This program attempts to rename a file named
```

* CRT_RENAMER.OBJ to CRT_RENAMER.JBO. For this operation
 * to succeed, a file named CRT_RENAMER.OBJ must exist and
 * a file named CRT_RENAMER.JBO must not exist.
 */

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int  result;
   char old[] = "CRT_RENAMER.OBJ", new[] = "CRT_RENAMER.JBO";

   /* Attempt to rename file: */
   result = rename(old, newArray);
   if(result != 0)
      printf("Could not rename '%s'\n", old );
   else
      printf("File '%s' renamed to '%s'\n", old, newArray);
}
```

Comment: Uhh.. did you just seriously name an array `new` in c++?

Comment: This is just eg of array name....you can make change in you code as you requirement..